# ftp batch file task scheduler lcd command not working

Tags: ftp, scheduled-tasks, cd

I have an FTP batch file running in task scheduler. The batch file contains the following line of code.

```
call ftp -s:ftplogin.txt xx.xx.xx.xx >> FTPLog
```

The ftplogin.txt file contains

```
username
password
cd /remote/directory/
lcd C:\local\dir\
get remotefile.txt localfile.txt
bye
```

The location of the batch file and the input file is on a folder on c drive.

Then I use the task scheduler to execute the batch file, I have to provide a "Start in" argument or else it does not run. it errors out with a hexadecimal 0x2 code.

When I do, execute the task, the file that is received via ftp is deposited in the same directory as the batch file. The "lcd" command does not have any effect.

Any ideas why ? The taskscheduler is on windows server 2008 R2

Thanks,
Paras

Comment: you should be able to do `get /remote/directory/remotefile.txt c:\local\dir\localfile.txt` without having to do any cding.

Comment: Still the same result. when I double click on the .bat file, it works fine but when I execute it in task scheduler, it puts the file in the same folder as the .bat file.